# PubNative integration ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I integrate pubnative library in my project , but it load only one app in my table view and i don't want tihis. I want to populate my table view with all partener apps that i have. When i lunch the app date are diffrent every time .

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    PNAdRequestParameters *parameters = [PNAdRequestParameters requestParameters];
    [parameters fillWithDefaults];
    parameters.ad_count = @5;
    parameters.app_token = @"My app token";
    parameters.icon_size=@"400x400";


    self.request = [PNAdRequest request:PNAdRequest_Native
                         withParameters:parameters
                          andCompletion:^(NSArray *ads, NSError *error)
                    {
                        if(error)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Pubnative - Request error: %@", error);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Pubnative - Request end");
                            weakSelf.ads = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:ads];
                            weakSelf.model = [ads firstObject];
                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                        }
                    }];
    [self.request startRequest];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [PNTableViewManager controlTable:self.tableView];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [PNTableViewManager controlTable:nil];
}




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *result = nil;

        PNBannerTableViewCell *bannerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bannerCellID];
        if(!bannerCell)
        {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PNBannerTableViewCell"
                                                                     owner:self options:nil];
            bannerCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }

        bannerCell.model = self.model;
        result = bannerCell;

    return result;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should then assign a different ad each time

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cell ForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *result = nil;

    PNBannerTableViewCell *bannerCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:bannerCellID];
    if(!bannerCell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PNBannerTableViewCell"
                                                                 owner:self options:nil];
        bannerCell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // We assign an add to the table
    bannerCell.model = self.ads[indexpath.row % [self.ads count]];
    result = bannerCell;

    return result; 
}
```